# I filed form 2553, but no confirmation from IRS. What to do?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, s-corporation

I filed form 2553 and faxed it to the IRS twice, and received confirmations of the fax receipt twice, but I have received no confirming correspondence from the IRS. It seems nearly impossible to get the IRS on the phone, so how does one confirm they have processed this correctly? Or should I just proceed to file as an S-corp regardless?

Answer (score 2):

You should receive [the CP261 notice](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/understanding-your-cp261-notice) once the form is accepted. Alternatively you will receive [the CP264 notoce](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/understanding-your-cp264-notice) if your request is denied. These should be sent to you within 60 days. You can also request a formal S election confirmation from the IRS by phone at 800-829-4933.

> Or should I just proceed to file as an S-corp regardless?

Yes, but be prepared to amend your filings if your election is denied.